# How can I get only unique objects from JSON with the following conditions in angularjs

Tags: angularjs

How can I get only unique objects from JSON with the following conditions:

- `processed == true`
- `selected.type === 'Intercompany' || payee.selected.type === 'Intercompany - OT'`

I don’t want to write a separate JavaScript function. Trying to achieve that in HTML.

My HTML So far:

```
<div data-ng-repeat="payee in data.contacts  | filter: {processed:true }">
    <blink data-ng-if="payee.selected.type === 'Intercompany' || payee.selected.type === 'Intercompany - OT'"><span class="pinkVouchers">PAID Vouchers - {{payee.selected.title}} - {{payee.selected.type}}</span></blink>
</div>
```

My JSON:

```
[
  {    
    "hidden": true,
    "processed": true,
    "selected": {
      "title": "Test Assessor 2",
      "userId": "1082495",
      "name": "Test Assessor 2",
      "province": "Ontario",
      "custId": "133300",
      "groupId": "",
      "regNo": "Yes",
      "type": "Intercompany"
    }
  },
  {
    "hidden": true,
    "processed": true,
    "selected": {
      "title": "Test Atkins",
      "userId": "1155027",
      "name": "Test Atkins",
      "province": "British Columbia",
      "custId": "1234",
      "groupId": "",
      "regNo": "No",
      "type": "Intercompany"
    }
  },
  {
    "hidden": true,
    "processed": true,
    "selected": {
      "title": "Test Assessor 2",
      "userId": "1082495",
      "name": "Test Assessor 2",
      "province": "Ontario",
      "custId": "133300",
      "groupId": "",
      "regNo": "Yes",
      "type": "Intercompany"
    }
  },
  {
    "hidden": false,
    "processed": false,
    "selected": {
      "title": "Test Assessor",
      "userId": "1082466",
      "name": "Test Assessor",
      "province": "Ontario",
      "custId": "1111",
      "groupId": "",
      "regNo": "No",
      "type": "Intercompany - OT"
    }
  }
]
```

Comment: Haven't seen a blink tag in ages... I don't see anything inherently wrong here.  Can you make a reproducible example?

Comment: My code doesn't display unique records. it displays all records.

Comment: Based on the snippet you provided this is working as intended.  All entries type are either 'Intercompany' or 'Intercompany - OT'.

Comment: I am getting record Test Assessor 2 twice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was thinking the only way possible was with the [AngularJS Filter](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/filter). But I have found the difference between the version I was using and yours: the need to call the filter attributes like objects. Try this on ngRepeat:

```js
var module = angular.module("myModule", []);

module.controller("myController", function($scope) {
 $scope.message = "Test";
 $scope.myArray = [ {
  "hidden" : true,
  "processed" : true,
  "selected" : {
   "title" : "Test Assessor 2",
   "userId" : "1082495",
   "name" : "Test Assessor 2",
   "province" : "Ontario",
   "custId" : "133300",
   "groupId" : "",
   "regNo" : "Yes",
   "type" : "Intercompany"
  }
 }, {
  "hidden" : true,
  "processed" : true,
  "selected" : {
   "title" : "Test Atkins",
   "userId" : "1155027",
   "name" : "Test Atkins",
   "province" : "British Columbia",
   "custId" : "1234",
   "groupId" : "",
   "regNo" : "No",
   "type" : "Intercompany"
  }
 }, {
  "hidden" : true,
  "processed" : true,
  "selected" : {
   "title" : "Test Assessor 2",
   "userId" : "1082495",
   "name" : "Test Assessor 2",
   "province" : "Ontario",
   "custId" : "133300",
   "groupId" : "",
   "regNo" : "Yes",
   "type" : "Intercompany"
  }
 }, {
  "hidden" : false,
  "processed" : false,
  "selected" : {
   "title" : "Test Assessor",
   "userId" : "1082466",
   "name" : "Test Assessor",
   "province" : "Ontario",
   "custId" : "1111",
   "groupId" : "",
   "regNo" : "No",
   "type" : "Intercompany - OT"
  }
 } ];
  
  /*$scope.myArray = $scope.myArray.filter(function( obj ) { 
    return obj.processed && (obj.selected.type === 'Intercompany' || obj.selected.type === 'Intercompany - OT');
  });*/
});

module.filter('unique', function () {
  return function (collection) {
      var newCollection = [];
      angular.forEach(collection, function (item) {
        var isDuplicate = false;
        for (var i = 0; i < collection.indexOf(item); i++) {
          if (angular.equals(item, newCollection[i])) {
            isDuplicate = true;
            break;
          }
        }
        if (!isDuplicate) {
          newCollection.push(item);
        }

      });
    
    return newCollection;
  };
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.15/angular.min.js"></script>

<div ng-app="myModule">

 <div ng-controller="myController">

  <div ng-repeat="payee in myArray | filter : ({selected:{type: 'Intercompany'}} || {selected:{type:'Intercompany - OT'}}) && {processed:true} | unique">
   {{payee.selected.userId}}
    </div>


 </div>
</div>
```

Comment: When I use your statement: It doesn't display any records and I don't think it will display unique records . <div ng-repeat="payee in test | filter: ({selected.type:'Intercompany'} || {selected.type:'Intercompany - OT'}) && {processed:true}">

Comment: I get the following error when I use your statement. Error: [$parse:syntax] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.3.15/$parse/syntax?p0=.&p1=is%20unexpected%2C%20expecting%20%5B%3A%5D&p2=36&p3=data.contacts%20%20%7CNaNilter%3A%20(%7Bselected.type%3A'Intercompany'%7D%20%7C%7C%20%7Bselected.type%3A'Intercompany%20- undefined T'%7D)%20%26%26%20%7Bprocessed%3Atrue%7D&p4=.type%3A'Intercompany'%7D%20%7C%7C%20%7Bselected.type%3A'Intercompany%20- undefined T'%7D)%20%26%26%20%7Bprocessed%3Atrue%7D

Comment: Your solution is working with Angular 1.2.23 but it is not working with Angular 1.3.15.

Comment: Thanks now your solutions works with my version but I also need to display 1082495 only once. (Unique payee.selected.userId)